# MongoDB count distinct with value from another (join) collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, distinct

Looks like something very simple, but can't figure out.
I've got collection, say, Cars, which is:

```
{ _id: '123456789', make: 'Ferrari' }
```

and I've got users with car field which contains _id, not name:

```
{ _id: '111111111', email: 'some@em.ail', firstName: 'John', car: '123456789' },
{ _id: '222222222', email: 'oth@er.em.ail', firstName: 'Doe', car: '123456789' },
```

I want to get a list of distinct car makes. I can do ".distinct('car')" on users collection, but I'll get only _id's, not makes. And of course I can get the distinct _ids and then for each of them create request to DB, to get make by _id. But I'm pretty sure it can be done in one simple request, just can't understand how to distinct after aggregate

Comment: You can do this with a pipeline like `db.users.aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: 0,
        cars: { $addToSet: '$car' }
    } },
    { $lookup: {
       from: 'cars',
       localField: 'cars',
       foreignField: '_id',
       as: 'cars' 
    } },
    { $project: { cars: '$cars.make' } }
])`

Comment: @chridam, query wasn't working, but I put first line (with $group) after last line (with $project) and now I see some results that I can work with. If no one will give a better advise I'll mark your comment as the answer

Comment: If you want distinct car makes, what is the purpose of mentioning users?

Comment: because I have list of users and need to know distinct list of cars... things happen like that in real world applications